# Grouping by ranges in large table in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

Say I have a table like so

```
    id                      timestamp
    -------------------------------------
    1                       2019-06-15 17:00:00
    2                       2019-06-15 17:01:12
    3                       2019-06-15 17:02:54
    4                       2019-06-15 17:06:23
    5                       2019-06-15 17:10:59
```

...and so on for many rows.

I want to write a query that finds the number of id's (rows) within a certain range of time, say one hour. I know I can do this to find the count within two timestamps:

```
    SELECT COUNT(id)
    FROM table
    WHERE (timestamp
        BETWEEN TIMESTAMP '2019-06-15 17:00:00'
            AND TIMESTAMP '2019-06-15 18:00:00')
```

However, this is tedious as I would have to run this query for every successive range of timestamps. Is there a way to write a query that gives me the number of id's in every hour (17-18, 18-19, 19-20, ...) and groups them by range? I need it to work over consecutive days as well.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a derived table to list the hours you want and then use `JOIN`:

```
SELECT h.hh, COUNT(t.timestamp)
FROM (SELECT '2019-06-15 17:00:00' as hh UNION ALL
      SELECT '2019-06-15 18:00:00' as hh UNION ALL
      SELECT '2019-06-15 19:00:00' as hh UNION ALL
      SELECT '2019-06-15 20:00:00' as hh
     ) h LEFT JOIN
     t
     ON t.timestamp >= h.hh AND t.timestamp < h.hh + INTERVAL 1 HOUR
GROUP BY h.hh
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use `date()` to extract the day and `hour()` to extract the hour and gorup by them.

```
SELECT date(timestamp),
       hour(timestamp),
       count(id)
       FROM elbat
       GROUP BY date(timestamp),
                hour(timestamp);
```